# Image did not attach to mms

Tags: android, image, android-intent, attachment, mms

Why image not attach to mms? I want attach image to mms, but it is do no work, how i can make it?

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
sendIntent.putExtra("address", phonesBuilder2.toString());
sendIntent.setData(Uri.parse("smsto:" + phonesBuilder2.toString()));
sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "body text");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris.get(0));
startActivity(sendIntent);
```

Comment: Have you checked this `uris.get(0)` are you getting image from this??

Comment: Yes, i have image from uris.get(0)